# React Typescript: return array of Jsx elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying React and TypeScript, but there's little information.

I have this situation in JavaScript:

```
render: function() {

  var stars = [];

  for (var idx = 1; idx <= this.state.max; idx++) {
    var fill = idx <= this.props.data.score;
    var hover = idx <= this.state.hoverIndex;
    stars.push(<RatingStar fill={fill} index={idx} data={this.props.data} hoverFill={hover} hover={this.hoverStar} leave={this.leaveStar} />);
  }
  return stars;


}
```

This is easy in plain JavaScript. I simply return an array of elements. But in TypeScript this code gives me an error because `render()` returns a single JSX element, not an array. If I change the return type to array of JSX element, the error is class  doesn't implement React.component... So any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update

This will work React 16 and latest TypeScript definitions. The below answer is preserved for people on React 15 and below

## Old Answer

> render() return a single JSX element not an array

This is TypeScript actually helping you. *you must* return a single element from the `render`.

### Fix

Consider wrapping the output in a `div`. This might break your css so you need to think about reorganizing that as well.

Alternatively don't create a component and just `{callFoo()}` in JSX instead of `<Foo/>`.

Comment: Returning array of JSX elements is possible from React v16

Comment: If someone is looking for the typing of return value. I think `React.ReactNode` is the best way to type an array of JSX elements (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples)).

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you can return something like `<div>{stars}</div>`. I just learned that you can just return a whole array of JSX Elements like this, without having to use an iterator  (like `stars.map(star => {// render logic here})` or `{...stars}`) to unpack the array.

Comment: You can even use React fragments and instead of adding `div`, you can simply use `<>[Array JSX]</>` as return value.